# handling empty table when displaying view of data

Tags: laravel, forms, crud

I have a laravel project.  it has a table that I want to fill with data from a form.  Currently it populates the form with any data that may exist in the table.

I'm using @foreach to iterate through the data object.  This works fine when there is data in the table, but when there's no data obviously the @foreach data object will be empty..  How do folk handle this so that the form still shows with default values?

```
 @foreach($pricing as $price)
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-12">
    <p><strong>Rate</strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="hirePrice" class="">Hire Price</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" name="hire" class="form-control" placeholder="1200" aria-label="hireprice" id="hirePrice" value="{{ $price->hire}}">
```

Currently, if I empty the table, the page just displays the header and none of the html above, including the form fields.

edit:  The table will always only have 1 ROW !!   not sure if this makes it any easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use
 @isset($pricing)
 @foreach($pricing as $price)
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-12">
    <p><strong>Rate</strong></p>
.................................
 //your code
@endforeach
@endisset

Or, You can use if else condition like this:
@if($pricing != Null)
@foreach($pricing as $price)
<div class="form-row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-12">
    <p><strong>Rate</strong></p>
.....................
//code
@endforeach
@else 
<div>No data</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is not what I'm looking for.  I want to still show the same form as before but with empty data, however, I dont want to have to code and @else section with the same form/html data.. There must be an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Though i can not get your actual scenario,i can give some advice.
You can add one line condition inside of input tag like this:
HTML:
**<input type="text" @if($data->variable) value="{{ $data->variable }}" @else value=" " @endif >**

Otherwise, You can put same code within foreach loop into else condition. So, when data exists in the table, it shows the data in the form otherwise same form with empty value will appear.